# Need an example when the space of bounded linear maps is not complete

Tags: functional-analysis

I know that if Y is complete then the space of bounded linear maps from X to Y is complete. What happens if X is complete but Y is not complete ? Can you please give me an example where the space of linear maps in this case becomes incomplete?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y$ be any non-complete normed linear space. Thus, there is some Cauchy sequence $(y_n)$ in $Y$ that does not converge.

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$, and define a sequence $(T_n)$ in $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ by
$T_n(1)=y_n$. Then the sequence $(T_n)$ is Cauchy in $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ because $$\|T_n-T_m\|_{\mathcal{L}(X,Y)}=\|y_n-y_m\|_Y,$$ but it cannot converge to any $T\in\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ because then we would have $y_n=T_n(1)\to T(1)\in Y$.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you want, you can accept my answer as described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/161783